# Forgot to name file in sudo mv command

Tags: files, mv

I've mistakenly put the following command

```
sudo mv www_sslcertificaten_nl.key ../../identimo
```

I wanted to move the .key file two folders down and in another folder, but I forgot to place the filename after it, and now I can't find the file anymore. I've used ls-lah on every nearby folder but the file is nowhere to be found, not even as '....'.

Is there any way to retrieve the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If the relative path `../../identimo` denotes a *directory*, then you will find the file `www_sslcertificaten_nl.key` in that directory.  In this case, it may have overwritten another file if that other file had the same name as the file that you moved.

If the path denotes a *file*, then the file `www_sslcertificaten_nl.key` is now called `identimo` and is located two directories up from where you executed the command (in `../../`). The command renamed the file and moved it.  Again, if there was already a file with the name `identimo` in that directory, it will have been overwritten by the file that you moved.

Comment: You're fast as a shark @Kusalananda!

Comment: @maulinglawns As a shrek more like it.  :-)

Comment: You are far from a troll :-)

Comment: Hi Kusalananda, thanks for your reply. The problem is, I think I've renamed the file the same as the already excisting folder 'Identimo' which was two folders down. So is my file now lost because there was already a folder with the exact name?

Comment: @Bas No, it will be located inside that folder.  Also, one usually say "up" about `..` as it points to the directory "above" the current directory in the directory hierarchy.

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry for my wrong term usage, thanks for correcting me. Inside that folder I only see 2 files which I know should be there, and a '.' and '..', so I guess the file is lost then? Thanks for helping me out

Comment: @Bas Did you actually end up executing the command at all? Is the command in the question the command that you ran? Was the file available in the current directory? If so, the file should have been moved. The `mv` utility would definitely *not* delete the file.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've checked all folders, the original file is not in the original location and the other folders do not contain any other files. I've generated a new .key file and the problem is solved tho. Thanks for helping me :)